# Need Custom Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, meter

I have data in table

[image]

I want Last Month Consumption and Last Three Month Consumptions

for example basis on Reading

[image]

I have tried this:

```
SELECT tbl.CustomerID
    ,tbl.CustomerName
    ,tbl2.Last3Months
    ,tbl.LastMonth
FROM (
    SELECT events.event_item_id CustomerID
        ,items.item_name CustomerName
        ,MAX(events.event_additional_info) maxR
        ,MIN(events.event_additional_info) minR
        ,(MAX(events.event_additional_info) - MIN(events.event_additional_info)) AS LastMonth
    FROM events
    INNER JOIN items ON events.event_item_id = items.item_id
    WHERE (events.event_additional_info <> '0.000000')
        AND (
            events.event_timestamp BETWEEN '08-MAY-15 12:00:00 AM'
                AND '08-Jun-15 6:21:59 PM'
            )
    GROUP BY events.event_item_id
        ,items.item_name
    ) tbl
    ,(
        SELECT events.event_item_id CustomerID
            ,items.item_name CustomerName
            ,MAX(events.event_additional_info) maxR
            ,MIN(events.event_additional_info) minR
            ,(MAX(events.event_additional_info) - MIN(events.event_additional_info)) AS Last3Months
        FROM events
        INNER JOIN items ON events.event_item_id = items.item_id
        WHERE (events.event_additional_info <> '0.000000')
            AND (
                events.event_timestamp BETWEEN '08-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM'
                    AND '08-Jun-15 6:21:59 PM'
                )
        GROUP BY events.event_item_id
            ,items.item_name
        ) tbl2
WHERE tbl2.CustomerID = tbl.CustomerID
```

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: can u create query? i tried a lot but failed.

Comment: You need to get the min and max dates for the 2 periods (4 dates total), select the value corresponding to those dates and take the difference by Meter. This site is not for having someone else write your code for you, rather helping you deal with problems in your existing attempts.

Comment: This looks like a homework to me!

Comment: @InHouseToday-IHT you will need to show us what you have tried so far. You said you have `tried a lot but failed`. We don't know what you have tried.

Comment: i have edit the question with i have tried. @Nepali Rokie,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a schema, so I worked from this:

```
DECLARE @MeterReading TABLE( ID INT, ReadingDate DateTime, Reading MONEY)
```

The SQL `DateDiff` function is the key. Given an input of an "As Of" date (that can default via `GETDATE()`, you can get the readings within the last month (DATEDIFF = 0) and within months 0, 1, and 2 (therefore 3 months).

The first query (in the WITH clause) both limits the data to 3 months and finds the max/min for each month.

The final query is then pretty simple

```
DECLARE @ASOF DateTime = GETDATE();  -- semicolon is important here!

WITH monthreadinds as (SELECT id
                        , DATEDIFF(MONTH,mr.ReadingDate , @ASOF) as WhichMonthAgo
                        , MIN(reading) as MinReading
                        , max(reading) as MaxReading
                    FROM @MeterReading mr
                    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,mr.ReadingDate , @ASOF)  <= 2  -- very important (limits to 3 months)
                    group by ID, DATEDIFF(MONTH,mr.ReadingDate , @ASOF) 
                    )
SELECT id,
    SUM( CASE WHEN mr.WhichMonthAgo = 0 THEN mr.MaxReading -  mr.MinReading  ELSE 0 END ) as LastMonthConsumption,
    MAX(mr.MaxReading) -  MIN(mr.MinReading)   as Last2MonthsConsumption
FROM  monthreadinds mr
GROUP by id
```